# swift file not linked to sks file and not changing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, skscene

So I have a game so far and everything seems to be working very well. I'm only using the basic gamescreen.swift that is default project along with the .sks file for it as well. After a certain condition is met (opponent winning by certain amount of points), it transitions to the .sks file. I even double checked by removing the .sks file to see if it was maybe just transitioning to the .swift file but when I did that I got the nil error (for obvious reasons).

So when I do things like (below) on the .swift file it should theoretically change the .sks file and how it looks visually when I build, but it doesn't. Nothing happens

```
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "theimage")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(background)
}
```

So then I remove everything from the .swift file and instead manually add the image to the .sks file and it doesn't do a single thing when I build it.

So I'm thinking, maybe it's just not even showing the .sks file, but rather a random thing. So I changed the background of the .sks file and built it and the change occurred. I made sure I checked with multiple colors and it didn't work. I just was wondering why if I manually add image to the .sks it's not working yet when I change background image it does...hm

Answer (score 0):

Next time if anyone encounters this make sure that the image you're trying to add as a node isn't significantly large. That was my issue but when I resized the image it all worked out :D